# Problems getting the size of an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, grep, do-while

I have this code to get all the lines filtered by the expression used the grep:

```
arrvar=( $(grep -Poh '^[A-Z_]+=.+' input.txt) )
arrlen=${#arrvar[@]}

i=0
while : ; do

    split=(${arrvar[i]//=/ })

    name="${split[0]}"
    value="${split[1]}"

    echo "index..: $i"
    echo "name...: $name"
    echo "value..: $value"

    i=$(( i + 1 ))
    if [ $i > $arrlen ]; then
      break
    fi
done
```

Whit this content in input.txt:

```
HELLO=111
STACK=222
OVERFLOW=333
```

The result is the following:

```
index..: 0
name...: STACK
value..: 222
```

Why only returns the first item of the array instead the three of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing like this:

```
if [ $i > $arrlen ]
```

but you probably mean

```
if (( i > arrlen ))
```

`[` compares lexicographically while `((` compares numerical.

Comment: +1: Though he'll probably need `>=` to prevent extra lines of data with nothing in it.

Comment: Or `[ $i -gt $arrlen ]`